# How to upload large files to stackoverflow that have no extension?

Tags: github

I'm trying to push my project to github yet it complains:

```
remote: error: File Godot.app/Contents/MacOS/Godot is 156.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I tried downloading Git Large File Storage, but it seems to require a file extension to work. As you can see my file does not have an extension.

How can I upload it to github?

Comment: You're really better off not storing actual executables or shared libraries in your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it seems to require a file extension to work

Strange, considering [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 712](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/712) does mention:

> You can specify any filename or path in your repository.
> You aren't limited to using file extensions.
>
> You could also track a specific directory with `git lfs track 'assets/*'` or an entire directory tree with `git lfs track 'assets/**/*'`.
> You could also track individual files specifically with `git lfs track path/to/file`, which will track only that file.

That being said, any generated executable (like a [GotDot app one](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_osx.html)) would not, ideally, be pushed.

Comment: How can I add /Applications/godot-3.3.2-stable/Godot.app to the git ignore file? I've tried every possible way I can think of writing the path name and it doesnt ignore it...

Comment: @RichardGarfield You need to remove it first: `git rm -r --cached -- /Applications/godot-3.3.2-stable/Godot.app` (assuming `/Applications` is part of your Git repository). Then your `.gitignore` would work.